# Populating mongoose schema with graphql and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

Hey guys i was using graphql with mongoose and nodejs here so my schema is like this

booking.js

```
const mogoose = require("mongoose");
const autopopulate = require('mongoose-autopopulate')
const Schema = mogoose.Schema;
const bookingSchema = new Schema({

  event:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Event',
    autopopulate:true
  },
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports=mogoose.model('Booking',bookingSchema.plugin(autopopulate))
```

event.js

```
const mogoose = require("mongoose");
const autopopulate = require('mongoose-autopopulate')
const Schema = mogoose.Schema;
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  creator:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User',
    autopopulate:true
  }
});

module.exports=mogoose.model('Event',eventSchema.plugin(autopopulate))
```

then in my resolver for deleting an event i did somehting like this

```
cancelEvent: async (args) => {
    try {
      const booking = await Booking.findById(args.bookingID);
        const event={...booking.event,_id:booking.event._id}
       await Booking.deleteOne({ _id: args.bookingID });
       return event
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  },
```

console.log(event._doc) gives me

```
{ _id: 5eb94b2ee627fc04777835d2,
  title: '22222',
  description: 'sd',
  date: 'df',
  creator:
   { createdEvents:
      [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _id: 5eb80367c2483e16a9e86502,
     email: 'sdd',
     password:
      '$2a$12$3lNyWl8w9gWLo8TtJDL2Te6Wg6psQOrOveinifFF4Jjeij9b4P2Ga',
     __v: 16 },
  __v: 0 }
```

so lets say my db is like

```
_id:ObjectId("5eb96b75c43aca45ff6aa934")
user:ObjectId("5eb80367c2483e16a9e86502")
event:ObjectId("5eb94b2ee627fc04777835d2")
createdAt:"2020-05-11T14:42:22.470+00:00"
updatedAt:"2020-05-11T14:42:22.470+00:00"
__v:"0"
```

after then i wrote my graphql query

```
mutation{
  cancelEvent(bookingID:"5eb96b75c43aca45ff6aa934"){
   _id,
    event{
      title
    }  
  }
}
```

the result i get back is

```
{
  "data": {
    "cancelEvent": {
      "_id": "5eb94b2ee627fc04777835d2",
      "event": null
    }
  }
}
```

the id is of the event that i am returning in resolver but then event title is null, 
even if i tried

```
mutation{
  cancelEvent(bookingID:"5eb96b75c43aca45ff6aa934"){
   title

  }
}
```

it says

> cannot query field title on type Booking

so how i fetch title of the event that was associated with booking just deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `cancelEvent` to return `Booking`, then this mutation is already correct

```
mutation {
  cancelEvent(bookingID:"5eb96b75c43aca45ff6aa934"){
   _id,
    event {
      title
    }  
  }
}
```

But in your resolver you have to return `booking` and not `event`.

```js
      const booking = await Booking.findById(args.bookingID);
      await Booking.deleteOne({ _id: args.bookingID });
      return booking
```

**Otherwise** If you want to return `event` then you will have to change the type of `cancelEvent` mutation to `Event`

In that case you can use this mutation

```js
mutation {
  cancelEvent(bookingID:"5eb96b75c43aca45ff6aa934") {
    title
  }
}
```

With the following resolver

```js
      const booking = await Booking.findById(args.bookingID);
      await Booking.deleteOne({ _id: args.bookingID });
      return booking.event
```

Comment: ahh found out the return type of cancelEvent was booking instead of Event type